# Xamarin sample project not loading in Visual Studio Blend

Tags: xamarin

[image]

1/ I am new for Xamarin and VS Blend.
2/ I installed Xamarin, i was checked i already have Visual Studio

3/ I download Xamarin sample project from link https://github.com/xamarin/recipes

I tried to open one of android project from these sample but when i choose and open it then it is showing "unavailable" where project folder. you can see in attached image.

Comment: Hi Friends, I completely uninstall Microsoft Blend from my laptop, and then i installed Microrsoft Visual Studio community  from Xamarin website. but still when i tried to open same xamarin sample project , showing same problem(showing unavailable) in Solution Explorer, I really dont know why i am still unable to open the project with IDE downloaded from Xamarin website.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Microsoft Blend does not support the Xamarin-based XAML format as Blend uses its own internal parser and it does not support 3rd-party XAML variants via plugins.

I *assume* and hope that with the merger of Xamarin complete, there will be a future release of Blend that does support it...

So like Xamarin users have be doing for the past year+, you need to handwrite your XAML files:

Ref: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/2026256-why-doesn-t-the-visual-studio-xaml-designer-work-for-xamarin-forms-xaml-files-

Comment: Thanks, so for working with those sample projects, i needs to download Microsoft Community 2015 from xamarin website?

Comment: Sounds like you already have the add-in installed for Visual Studio so you do not have to do anything else, you should be able to open the solutions and proceed from there, you just can not use Blend, you will need to edit the XAML-based UI screens (if the project is Xamarin.Forms based) in Visual Studio as a text file.

Comment: I do belive most people seriously using Xamarin have developed their own alternatives for dynamically uploading xaml into the app / emulator for preview, or are using "Xaml Player" or "Gorilla player" or similar. Let's hope you are right and Blend starts supporting Xamarin xaml. That'd be awesome!

Comment: @irreal It would be nice. We currently do not use Xamarin.Forms/XAML in production apps and instead go "native" UI for all of our apps so far. The overhead (performance and memory) are just to heavy. the 2.0 release help a lot but the perf different was still to much. We are hoping the new Forms 2.1 along with the new Xamarin Android Java-Bridge (currently in Alpha) will meet our requirements, but not sure about iOS... fingers crossed ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Yeah, I actually meant "most people seriously using Xamarin.Forms". I understand your decision to go with native UI's. We would do the same, but we have a huge number of screens and would loose the point of shared code if our UI wasn't shared as well. So we just got really good at optimizing xaml forms :)

Comment: Hi Friends, I completely uninstall Microsoft Blend from my laptop, and then i installed Microrsoft Visual Studio community from Xamarin website. but still when i tried to open same xamarin sample project , showing same problem(showing unavailable) in Solution Explorer, I really dont know why i am still unable to open the project with IDE downloaded from Xamarin website.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a Xamarin-Project in Blend. It has an integrated Designer for Android and a remote Designer for IOS (You need a MAC Build-Agent for this to work).